# Reverse list order without increasing complexity

Tags: algorithm, list, haskell, time-complexity

I wanted an alternative to `filter` that would, instead of discarding the false cases, keep them in a separate place.  I came up with the below, but unfortunately it reverses the list.

Obviously I could append x to ys or zs instead of cons, but this would dramatically increase complexity.

Is there a way to keep it in order without increasing complexity?

```
splitBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitBy f xs = splitBy' f xs ([],[])
            where
                splitBy' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a]) -> ([a],[a])
                splitBy' _   []   result  = result
                splitBy' f (x:xs) (ys,zs) = if f x then splitBy' f xs (x:ys,zs)
                                                   else splitBy' f xs (ys,x:zs)
```

Comment: A [hoogle search](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3EBool%29-%3E%5Ba%5D-%3E%28%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%29) shows that this function is called `partition`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, going to find the source and see if it keeps them in order without increasing complexity.  I'm new to Haskell and not used to looking in places except the prelude.

Comment: study [the source code for `partition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#partition): it effectively adds elements to the end of a list as it is being built (the both of them).  Lazy pattern (the `~`) allows for infinite list as an input (e.g. `take 10 $ fst $ partition odd [1..]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the function is called `partition`, and it works something like this

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
partition f = foldr (\x ~(yes,no) ->
                         if f x
                         then (x:yes,no)
                         else (yes,x:no))
                    ([], [])
```

except that the real version adds an explicit `xs` parameter, perhaps to help fusion rules work properly. If that funky lazy pattern match makes you nervous, you can write it like this instead:

```
partition f = foldr (\x r ->
                         if f x
                         then (x:fst r,snd r)
                         else (fst r,x:snd r))
                    ([], [])
```

If the `foldr` seems mysterious to you, you can do it like this:

```
partition f [] = ([], [])
partition f (x:xs)
  | f x       = (x:fst r, snd r)
  | otherwise = (fst r, x:snd r)
  where r = partition f xs
```

Comment: you could use `(yes,no)` pattern in your last version, with `where`.

Comment: @WillNess, this is true, although changing the second version to match might be a bit awkward.